# const& vector member initialized with const& vector in ctor

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, reference, constants

I have the following code in which I have member *v_*, a const
reference to a vector of ints. It is initialized with an lvalue, so my
thinking is this should not cause any copy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using Vec = std::vector<int>;

void out(Vec const& v) {
  using namespace std;
  cout << "Vector (" << &v[0] << "): [";
  ostream_iterator<int> out_it (cout,", ");
  copy(v.begin(), v.end(), out_it);
  cout << "]\n";
}

struct V {
  V(Vec const& v) : v_{v}{}
  Vec const& v_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Vec v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  out(v);
  V wrapped { v };
  out(wrapped.v_);
}
```

With *clang version 3.6.0 (trunk 225298)* I get the following output:

```
~/tmp$ clang++ -std=c++11 -g -O0 vecmember.cpp
~/tmp$ ./a.out
Vector (0x2480010): [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ]
Vector (0x2480010): [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ]
```

This is what I hoped for.
However, with *c++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2* I get the following output:

```
~/tmp$ c++ -std=c++11 -g -O0 vecmember.cpp
~/tmp$ ./a.out
Vector (0xa58010): [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ]
Vector (0xa58030): []
```

When I step into the debugger it goes into *stl_vector.h* function *vector(const vector& __x)* so it is trying to copy construct the original vector passed to the constructor. Is this a compiler bug or am I somehow doing something undefined or just plain wrong?

In either case, what is a better approach?

Comment: There was a defect in the standard with list-initialization and references. GCC 4.8 implemented the standard to the letter (including the defect). The standard defect was later fixed, and GCC 4.9 implements the fix.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1288

Comment: @T.C. Yes, that is the answer, want to write it as one? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++11 standard actually said that when you list-initialize a reference like this:

```
int i;
int & ir{i};
```

it constructs a temporary and then binds the reference to the temporary. (And in the above example it would fail because a non-const lvalue reference cannot be bound to a temporary.)

Obviously this makes absolutely no sense whatsoever; it's a defect in the standard. Unfortunately, GCC 4.8 implemented this part of the standard to the letter, at least in member initializer lists of constructors. As a result, `v_{v}` constructed a temporary `std::vector` and bound that temporary to `v_` (the binding succeeds because `v_` is a const reference); the lifetime of the temporary ends at the end of the constructor, and the reference becomes dangling, meaning that your second `out` call has undefined behavior.

The standard defect was fixed by the resolution of [CWG issue 1288](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1288), and this fix was implemented in GCC 4.9 (see [GCC bug 50025](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50025)). The workaround if you are stuck with GCC 4.8 is to use the old initialization syntax `v_(v)`.